# Disjunctive filter in SPARQL query

Tags: filter, sparql, logical-or

I want to search a case law database for a specific title. I look for that title in the `?title` and `?alttitle` properties, using `FILTER` and `||` (logical-or).

Now I have noticed that this only seems to yield results when both FILTER conditions are true. So, the example below yields no results, even though the value of the `?alttitle` field in the record I'm looking for is "NTN Toyo Bearing and Others v Council" and the value of the `?title` field is "NTN Toyo Bearing Company Ltd and others v Council". I would expect the fact that there is a match in the `?alttitle` property to be sufficient when using `||`.

How can I make sure that this record is returned even if there is only a match with the `?alttitle` value? Additionally, any tips to make this query faster are appreciated.

SPARQL Endpoint: http://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql

```
PREFIX cdm: <http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?work ?expression ?ecli ?celex ?alttitle ?agname ?title
WHERE {{{
?work a ?class.
?expression cdm:expression_belongs_to_work ?work.
?expression cdm:expression_title ?title.
?expression cdm:expression_uses_language <http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/language/ENG>.
?work cdm:case-law_ecli ?ecli.
?work cdm:resource_legal_id_celex ?celex.

OPTIONAL{?expression cdm:expression_case-law_parties|cdm:expression_title_alternative ?alttitle}
}

                  
FILTER(?class in (<http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#judgement>,<http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#opinion_cjeu>))
FILTER (CONTAINS(?alttitle, "NTN Toyo Bearing and Others v Council")||CONTAINS(?title,"NTN Toyo Bearing v Council"))}

UNION{?work a ?class.
?expression cdm:expression_belongs_to_work ?work.
?expression cdm:expression_title ?title.
?expression cdm:expression_uses_language <http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/language/ENG>.
?work cdm:case-law_ecli ?ecli.
?work cdm:resource_legal_id_celex ?celex.
?work cdm:case-law_delivered_by_advocate-general ?ag.
?ag cdm:agent_name ?agname.

OPTIONAL{?expression cdm:expression_case-law_parties|cdm:expression_title_alternative ?alttitle}

         }
FILTER(?class in (<http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#opinion_advocate-general>))
FILTER (CONTAINS(?alttitle, "NTN Toyo Bearing and Others v Council")||CONTAINS(?title,"NTN Toyo Bearing v Council"))}

LIMIT 15
```

Comment: there is some encoding "issue" of the data (let's call it hidden pitfall): I mean, it works with a filter in the first 4 words: `FILTER ( contains(str(?alttitle), "NTN Toyo Bearing and"))` but even an additional single space char makes the resultset empty: `FILTER ( contains(str(?alttitle), "NTN Toyo Bearing and "))` - if you take your query with the working filter and ask for N-Triples as result instead of HTML, you'll see that the literal is `NTN Toyo Bearing and\u00A0Others v Council` - the unicode char is a "NON-BREAKING SPACE": https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

Comment: by the way, the filters for the second `UNION` clause are outside of the union - I don't think this was intended

Comment: Well-spotted, and helpful method for future troubleshooting. Indeed, further testing confirmed that neither of both conditions were true as a result of this one non-breaking space. So `||` does work as expected.

Comment: Feel free to post this as an answer!